# Remove leading single quote before computation in SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql

I need to compare two account number columns from two different tables to see if they match. The account number in one table has a leading single quote and the other does not. My question is how would I ignore or remove the leading quote before I made the comparison in my query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function can be used to trim the first character off the field ie

SUBSTRING(field1, 2)

I would be questioning why the field is being stored with the single quote in the first place.

Comment: And of course, many similar functions in other databases. E.g., it's called `SUBSTR` in Oracle. OP should check his/her database documentation for the correct function in the relevant database.

Comment: It is imported from a excel spread sheet and the leading single quote is so leading zeros don't get chopped off. Thanks

Comment: To provide an example using Dave's answer: `select t1.cardnumber, t2.cardnumber from cardtablewithquote1 as t1 inner join cardtable2 as t2 on substring(t1.cardnumber from 2) = t2.cardnumber` <-- this can help if getting all the matching records based on card number

Comment: Im getting a error that is saying subsrting requires three arguments.This is my query CASE WHEN dbo.Frost.[RTNum] <> SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_RoutingNo, 1) THEN 'DO not match' WHEN dbo.Frost.[RTNum] = SUBSTRING(dbo.ternean.ACH_RoutingNo, 1) THEN 'match' END AS [Routing # match]

Answer (score 1):

**Substring** makes a lot of sense if the data ALL begins with a single quote.   Just be careful that if some fields do not, the **substring()** solution will not work..    You can also use

```
replace(field1,'''','')
```

but this will only work if there is only one single quote in the field.

Answer (score 1):

And for the seriously over-engineered answer... :)

If you're going to need any sort of performance for this (like you're calling it in a loop or across a large amount of records), you may want to consider making a function to normalize the input to remove the leading quote if present (especially if you don't have an external way of telling if there will be a leading quote or not).  For string manipulations like this, [SQL CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) functions are usually an order of magnitude faster than doing the same manipulations in SQL.  Take a look [here](http://www.sqlclr.net/) for more information.